# How do you determine the number of messages left in your subcriber buffer queue?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have a subscriber with a buffer size of 10, and my callback has dealt with 3 messages, is there a way to access the number of messages left in the queue ( retrieve the value of 7 )?

Basically I want my subscriber to deal with a batch of messages, and then do some task once they have all come through, then deal with the next batch of messages, and then do the task again. I do not know the size of the batch of messages.

Ideally I just need an indication that the buffer is empty.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249481/how-do-you-determine-the-number-of-messages-left-in-your-subcriber-buffer-queue?/) by [Grim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26585/grim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-12-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Push your messages shared_ptr to another data structure as they come in (such as std::queue), and do your batch processing there instead.

The inner workings of the ROS subscriber's message buffer are not exposed through the roscpp API.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2016-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26585/grim/) on 2016-12-07**:
While I think this may be a solution, I don't know how to do it. I have not dealt with std::shared_ptr or std::queue. And I am not sure if learning it right now would be worth my time for this project. This also needs to be memory efficient since the messages themselves are quite large.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2016-12-07**:
You'd be pushing the boost::shared_ptr to the message (as received by your callback, ConstPtr) to the queue, so memory impact would be negligible.

If you're going to work with C++, I suggest becoming very familiar with the basics of std, particularly containers (http://en.cppreference.com/w/)